# Dialog não abre

Tags: primefaces

Quando clico no botão novo deveria abrir uma janela de dialogo mas não abre e dá esse erro no console:

> widget for var 'teste' not available

O que pode ser ?

```
<ui:define name="menu">
    <ui:include src="/includes/menuPrincipal.xhtml"></ui:include>
</ui:define>



<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado"
            value="#{MBFrabicante.itens}" var="item" paginator="true" rows="10">

            <f:facet name="header">
                Fabricante - listagem
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Código" sortBy="#{item.codigo}"
                filterBy="#{item.codigo}">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.codigo}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Descrição">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.descricao}"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>

            <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton value="Novo" onclick="PF('teste').show();" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>

<p:dialog widgetVar="teste" resizable="false" header="Fabricante - Novo"
        modal="true" appendTo="@(body)">
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="Descrição: "></p:outputLabel>
            <p:inputText size="30" maxlength="50" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:commandButton value="Gravar" />
            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('dlgFabNovo').hide();" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Qual tema/template do Primefaces está sendo utilizada? Qual a versão?

Comment: O jar do primefaces é o 4.0 e está sendo utilizado o tema do twiter bootstrap. Mas já tentei mudar para um jar mais atualizado e não resolveu..

Comment: Já tentou colocar `<p:dialog>` dentro da tag `<ui:define name="conteudo">` ?

Comment: @DemetriusFernandes Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Vi que há um `form` dentro do `dialog`. Verifique se há um form dentro de outro, pois isso é uma das causas mais comuns de mau funcionamento do JSF.

Comment: Olá Demétrio. A janela de diálogo e o botão encontram-se no mesmo formulário? (Estou a  supor que definiste um formulário no template que utilizaste).

Answer (score 1):

Já tive esse problema, resolvi colocando o modal = "false". Não sei explicar o porque do problema com o modal = "true".

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="teste" resizable="false" header="Fabricante - Novo"
        modal="false" appendTo="@(body)">
```

Comment: Já passei pelo mesmo problema e resolvi da mesma forma.

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Dando uma olhada rápida eu percebi alguns detalhes que vc deixou passar por desatenção. Primeiro de tudo saiba que todos os componentes de ação do primefaces (commandXXXX) por padrão já fazem requisições via ajax. Quando você coloca um botão dentro de um formulário, quando ele for clicado, o formulário será submetido para o managedbean e se não houver navegação, a página atual só será recarregada. Sabendo disto, eu faço as seguintes considerações sobre seu código:

1 - Colocando type="button" no botão, o seu botão não irá submeter o formulario (e vc não quer submeter seu formulario apenas abrir o formulario pelo que percebi)

2 - A ação do seu botão de cancelar está tentando acessar o widgetvar de um compoente que não existe na pagina. Creio que vc queira nessa ação fechar o dialogo e portanto deveria ter utilizado "teste" para a função PF do primefaces

3 - Se os 2 pontos acima não resolverem, tente colocar o dialogo dentro da tag ui:define

No fim, utilizando os 3 pontos, ficaria assim:

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable>        
            (...)
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Novo" onclick="PF('teste').show();" type="button"/>
            </f:facet>

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog widgetVar="teste" resizable="false" header="Fabricante - Novo"
              modal="true" appendTo="@(body)">      
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="Descrição: "></p:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText size="30" maxlength="50" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:commandButton value="Gravar" />
                <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="PF('teste').hide();" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:define>
```

Qualquer coisa dá um feedback. Bom estudo!